# Not able to click on a button

Tags: java, html, selenium, iframe, selenium-webdriver

I am not able to click on an element with the HTML below. This button is on an iframe, I have switched over to the iframe and performed several other operations on the same iframe. This button exists on the same iframe but is not getting clicked and giving a **Element Not Visible Exception**

The html is:

```
/*html*/
<table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="55" valign="baseline" align="center">
<td width="55" valign="baseline" align="center">
<input id="next_per" class="Button" width="55" type="button" align="bottom" onclick="changeTab(2)" value=" Next ">
</td>
<td width="55" valign="baseline" align="center">
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi - I don't think you've included enough for us to help you out here. All I see is a normal-looking button which if I added it to *my* html pages would be clickable...  If your button is inside an iframe - you may need to give us the code with the iframe in it too. You can set this up in a fiddle to reproduce the problem? Can you click on it when you literally open the app in your own web browser and try clicking on it or does it only happen when yu do it via selenium? what else is happening in the selenium test before clicking this button (ie is there a modal covering the button) etc

Comment: This button is in an iframe. I have switched to this iframe. I am performing several operations in this iframe and afterwards clicking the button. The button is not getting clicked. What more information can i provide? Its a big page so posting all HTML wont help much i guess.

Comment: Don't describe it to me in words. "show don't tell" matters most for code. Edit your question and add all relevant code (including a run-through of the selenium test). the problem is that I don't know enough about your code, your setup etc to know what to ask you to give me the right information to help you... you need to think about it yourself and add everything you can. and No don't post *all* the code... post all the *relevant* code ;)

Comment: There is a separate table for all other operations and a separate table for button. I am writting and selecting from dropdowns before clicking on the button. Ill add more html to my question.

Comment: Stop describing it to me in words... and put the code in your question (also, don't put it in comments, actually edit your question and add it there so others don't have to red through all the comment so get it all)

Comment: is that double td a bug in your code or a copy/paste typo?

Comment: if you're selecting from dropdowns... it's possible that the dropdowns are covering over the button and the button is therefore not visible.

Comment: No. The other <td> contains the html of the other button. I only expanded the code of the button i want to click.

Comment: I can't really see dropdowns covering over the button when i play my selenium test. I dont think thats the issue. And i tried clicking on the button without performing any action too. It still didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dump the whole HTML of the `iframe` and search for `id="next_per"` in the dump. My guess is that there is more than one element with this ID.

If you have more than one element with the same ID, then it's undefined which one the browser will return when you do `getElementById()`. That's why you should make sure that all IDs in a single HTML document are unique.

Comment: The whole process includes 5 steps. This 'Next' button is on every single page with the same HTML. But the others are not yet visible.

Comment: Do they all have the same id? in which case this is your problem - it's finding the first one of that id (probably hidden and not visible) and trying that. ids need to be unique across the whole html page.

Comment: Yes the ids are same. This might be the problem. Thankyou!

Comment: I'll contact the developers and get it changed.